# Can I use this variable in linear regression?

Tags: regression, normalization, normality-assumption

I have an independent variable with the following distribution:

[image]

[image]

Can I use this variable in linear regression?  If not, can I transform it in any way?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Linear regression does not make assumptions about the distribution of your *independent* variables. It tends to make assumptions about the *residuals* from the model.

So yes, go ahead and include it. Just be sure to properly assess your model after you have fit it.

Comment: ... and investigate residuals after the fit!